# how to get submenu's handle in multi document project mfc

Tags: windows, mfc

I knew i can use `UPDATE_COMMAND_UI` to *enable/disable* `SubMenu` item, but I just want to ask why i can't use `Getmenu()`,`GetSubMenu()`, and `EnableMenuItem()` to *enable/disable* some SubMenus in multi document project.

Yes, i used `m_bAutoMenuEnable = false`, it didn't work with errors, but this way works well in single document project, so i feel strange here.

does anybody know why and how to fix it ? because if i use `UPDATE_COMMAND_UI` to *enable/disable* many submenus, it seems tedious.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not very sure, but for MDI you may need to set `m_bAutoMenuEnable` to `FALSE` in your child frame (normally `CChildFrame` in ChildFrm.cpp)

Comment: I tried to set set m_bAutoMenuEnable to FALSE in my child frame(ChildFrm.cpp) but when i use getmenu() getsubmenu() in Cmainfrm::oncreate() fuction, the error : "The activated context is not recently activated." came....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under normal circumstances, the state of the user interface reflects the state of the program.  For example, if the program is in read-only mode, then Edit commands should be disabled somewhere in the program.  Another example is if the clipboard content (a state) changes, then the menu paste (Paste) command should be disabled/enabled etc.

How to keep the user interface reflect the state of the program? There are two approaches:

1. Whenever the state of the program change, do not forget to update the user interface at the same time manually by calling `EnableMenuItem` in zillion places.
2. The second method is to relax, that is, do not try to maintain all the state information only as needed to update the user interface.  For the menu, the menu without maintaining status updates only when displayed profile. This method is easier, and is also very simple.  More importantly, it makes the data separated from the user interface.  Each object is stored only its own state. For example, a document know when it is in read-only mode.  The MFC framework provides a UI update mechanism to achieve that. The basic idea is this: when the user invokes a menu, Windows sends a `WM_INITMENUPOPUP` message.  The framework creates a temporary `CCmdUI` object to process the message, do continuous initialization and passes it to the application object for each menu item.  The `ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI` message processor is used to update the user interface.
   As long as the user enters the menu item the MFC calls `OnUpdateX()` function.  So you don't have to worry about all the places you must call in  `EnableMenuItem`.

If for some reason you still want to do it the old-fashion way using `EnableMenuItem` then you need to set `m_bAutoMenuEnable = FALSE;` in child frame not in main frame of your MDI app.

Comment: hi, thanks for your help, as you know i'm a noob here, i can't exactly understand what you said, but to set m_bAutoMenuEnable = FALSE; in child frame seems useless, i don't know wheter i did right thing or not, after set m_bAutoMenuEnable = FALSE; in child frame, when i use getmenu() getsubmenu() in CMainfrm::oncreate() fuction, the error : "The activated context is not recently activated." came...

Comment: here is the thing, i just want to do a validation during the program's initialization, if it's passed , then i will enable  specific submenu items... i do not konw if you can understand what i just said...whatever, thanks again..

Comment: Yeah, you'll face whole bunch of issues if you go against framework. You'll also have to set `m_hMenuDefault` to `NULL` and maybe hack some other stuff.